# How to add margin between grid items?

Tags: html, css

For some reason I cannot add margin between grid items 
[Page with margin issue](http://www.777auction.ca/online/index.php?module=listings&controller=browse&action=index&show=all&limit=80&page=1&sort=ending_asc&listing_type=auction)

This page margin shows perfectly:
[Proper page](http://www.777auction.ca/online/index.php?module=app&controller=index&action=index)

I suspect it has to do with CSS, I tried everything but nothing seemed to work. Can someone please help?

Comment: Please attach some code! ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is move your .grid class styling to a new parent element inside your grid column, the column itself takes up a full 25% of the width of the page and has internal padding to create the illusion of margin.

```
<div class="grid col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="grid">
```

You can see a quick example of this by moving your .grid class to the .description child element, the styling goes a bit wacky but you will be able to see the margins between your columns.